# i have a problem with dropdownLists

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a dictionary that looks like this `Dictionary<string,string[]>`

I also have 2 dropdownlist. I want the second dropdownlist present data depending on what the item from the first dropdropdownlist was chosen.

So i added an event to the second dropdownlist..here is the algorithm:

```
protected void topicDropDownMenu_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] chosenItem;
    chosenItem = null;
    SubTopicDropDownList.ClearSelection();

    chosenItem = topic[topicDropDownMenu.SelectedItem.Value];

    foreach (string item in chosenItem)
    {
        SubTopicDropDownList.Items.Add(item);
    }

}
```

what actually happens, is that an array of strings is added to the second dropdownlist each time i select an item from the first dropdownlist..

but i want the second dropdownlist to replace its values depending on what was chosen in the first dropdownlist, instead of adding those values to whatever was already placed in the second drop down list

Comment: After 61 questions, you should really learn how to format code and start each sentence with Upper case letter.

Comment: wizard, you are 100% right. not only when i ask questions, but also when i post comments xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// add this line - it's different from ClearSelection()
SubTopicDropDownList.Items.Clear();

foreach (string item in chosenItem)
{
    SubTopicDropDownList.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: No problem - that's the sort of thing you can look at for a long time and not notice :)

Answer (score 1):

Clear the items of the list before you reload it? See the [ListItemCollection.Clear Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.clear.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

`SubTopicDropDownList.ClearSelection()` doesn't empty the list, it just deselects the selected item. You can confirm this by looking at the value of `SelectedIndex`, `SelectedItem` or `SelectedValue` before and after making the call to `SubTopicDropDownList.ClearSelection()`. What you actually want to do is empty/clear the whole set of items, using `SubTopicDropDownList.Items.Clear()`.

So the correct code would be:

```
protected void topicDropDownMenu_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] chosenItem;
    chosenItem = null;
    ubTopicDropDownList.Items.Clear();

    chosenItem = topic[topicDropDownMenu.SelectedItem.Value];

    foreach (string item in chosenItem)
    {
        SubTopicDropDownList.Items.Add(item);
    }

}
```